# Rental payments

Tags: california

The property management company is now requiring credit cards or ACH accounts for paying rent. Is this legal to require or are renters still legally able to pay by check?

Comment: This also depends on the lease. If the landlord agreed to accept rent via check in the lease, they can't amend the lease unilaterally and remove that until the lease is renewed. The other answer says they must accept cash, but they don't necessarily have to accept checks, unless they said they would in the lease.

Comment: The issue here is, I think significantly different from the issue in the suggested duplicate.. There the landlord changed payment methods in mid-lease.

Answer (score -3):

No, a check is not legal tender and people do not have to accept it. Actual money is the only thing that has to be accepted to pay a debt.